# JSON saving issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to convert a BackboneJS app to plain jQuery. My previous Backbone app had some code that serialized a form (it used [this](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON)):

```
var json = $('#book_form').serializeJSON();

this.model.set(json);
this.model.save();
```

when sent to the server, it looked like:

```
{"book"=>{"name"=>"The Hilarious Book", "summary"=>"", "authors"=>[{"name"=>"Jeff", "college"=>"Harvard"}]}}
```

But with jQuery, now my code looks like:

```
var json = $('#book_form').serializeJSON();
$.ajax({
  url: "URL",
  type: "post",
  data: json
});
```

but when it is sent to the server, it looks like:

```
{"book"=>{"name"=>"The Hilarious Book", "summary"=>"", "authors"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Jeff", "college"=>"Harvard"}}}}
```

Comment: The version of serializeJSON is the same in both cases?

Comment: @GergoErdosi, Yes, I just copy and pasted the source to my newer project

Comment: What is the value if you do console.log(json) after the serialize call in both cases? You could try adding "processData: false" to your ajax options in the second case to see if that fixes it.

Comment: how does the json look like after the `serializeJSON ` call ?